# Measure in $\mathbb {C} ^p$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, pullback

If we have a non-constant holomorphic map $ f: \mathbb C ^ p \to X $, where $ X $ is a complex manifold. Let $ \omega $ be a metric  on $X$, so $ \omega $ is a positive definite $ (1,1) $-form.
Is $ f ^ * (\omega ^ p) $ a measure over $ \mathbb C ^ p $?

Comment: The grammar of what you wrote didn't make sense to me, so I made what seemed like a small change that hopefully preserved meaning.  I *think* that I didn't change the meaning, but please revert if I did.  (In that case, though, you might want to make sure to use $\mathbb C$ `$\mathbb C$` rather than $\ C$ `$\ C$` (a $C$ with a forced space beforehand) as you originally had.)

Comment: If $f$ is measurable, why not?

Comment: The fact that $f$ is not constant is sufficient or it is also necessary either of rank $=p$

Comment: Zero is a measure.

Comment: @Ben Mackay, Okay, if $f^*(\omega ^p) =0$, it implies that $f$ is a constant? Or just $f$ is with rank $<p$?

Comment: @Kamel: The pullback $f^*\omega^p$ vanishes just when $f$ has rank less than $p$ at every point of $\mathbb{C}^p$ mapping to a point of $X$ where $\omega\ne 0$.This is just determinant of a product is the product of determinants in local coordinates, or in a holomorphic basis of local sections of the cotangent bundle.

Comment: @Ben Mackay thank you

Answer (score 0):

A construction <del>impossible for $p > 1$</del> giving only zero for $\dim_\mathbb{C} X < p$ [see comments], for whichever reasonable meaning of “$\omega^p$” and pullback.

Denote by $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $w\in\mathbb{C}^{p-1}$  coordinates on $\mathbb{C}^p$.
Let $f := z$ with $X = \mathbb{C}$ (a standard projection).
Consider $(p\!-\!1)$-dimensional (over $\mathbb{C}$) affine transformations $A$ acting on $\mathbb{C}^p$ as
$$(z,w)\quad\mapsto\quad (z,Aw).$$
Does the action preserve $f$? Obviously. May the resulting measure be changed? Impossibly. Which measure can be invariant under *all* affine transformations of $w$? Only the zero measure.

$\omega$ may be $i(dz\wedge d\bar z)$ or whatever you like – the argument stands for any non-zero form. Ī̲ am puzzled how can this be a research-level math question.

Comment: The construction is not impossible; in fact it always well defined and always produces a measure, perhaps the zero measure. Your example produces the zero measure, since $\omega^2=0$ on $\mathbb{C}$. But on the other hand, other examples produce nonzero measures: if $f$ is any holomorphic map of $\mathbb{C}^p$, somewhere of full rank, and $X=\mathbb{C}^p$ and we take $\omega$ any Kaehler form, we get a measure $f^*\omega^p$ which is positive on any open set.

Comment: But I agree that the question is too elementary.

Comment: Oops, Ī̲ missed that $X$ is not (necessarily) one-dimensional.